# Python raw string notation on input from the user

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

How can i apply raw string notation on input from the user? For exmple, i want to get path from the user and enforce raw string notation on it, so if the input is something like:
"\path\the\user\chose" it will be accepted to the raw input / be converted later to r"\path\the\user\chose"

Comment: Raw string notation is only for _writing literals_ -- if you accept user input with backslashes in it, they will behave fine. No "conversion" is necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

Comment: @LironCohen Could you demonstrate how getting user input containing backslashes does *not* work?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this `path = input(r'Input your path:')`

It seems that `path` is something like `paht = \path\the\user\chose`

By the way, I use Python3.

Comment: Thanks bro, its really working for me, you saved my lot of time.